# I am getting results with SQL query but getting error with spark.Sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
accountBal.createOrReplaceTempView("accntBal")

    var finalDf = spark.sql(
" SELECT CTC_ID, ACCNT_BAL, PAID_THRU_DT, DAYS(CURRENT_DATE) - DAYS(PAID_THRU_DT) AS DEL_DAYS  FROM accntBal  WHERE ACCNT_BAL > 0  AND PAID_THRU_DT <= CURRENT_DATE AND PAID_THRU_DT > '01/01/2000'  AND PAID_THRU_DT is not null "
)
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'DAYS'

. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `DATEDIFF` to get the difference in days between two date:

```
SELECT
    CTC_ID,
   ACCNT_BAL,
   PAID_THRU_DT,
   DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, PAID_THRU_T) AS DEL_DAYS
FROM accntBal
WHERE
   ACCNT_BAL > 0 AND
   PAID_THRU_DT > '2000-01-01' AND PAID_THRU_DT <= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Note: The `NULL` check on `PAID_THRU_DT` is probably not necessary, since a `NULL` value would fail the range check already.

Answer (score 0):

In spark udf has to be registered to be used in your queries.

Register a function as a UDF

example :

```
val squared = (s: Long) => {
  s * s
}
spark.udf.register("square", squared)
```

since you have not registered `days` as it was throwing this error.

I assume you have written a custom udf to know number of days between 2 dates.

***How to debug ?***   :

To check your udf is there in the functions registerd with spark or not like [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html).

You can query for available standard and user-defined functions using the Catalog interface (that is available through SparkSession.catalog attribute).

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.show(false)
```

it will be display all the functions defined within spark session.

Further reading : [UDFs — User-Defined Functions](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html)

---

If not... you can try  which is already present in spark functions.scala

---

> static Column datediff(Column end, Column start) Returns the number of
>   days from start to end.